# Passing in ContentChildren as templates

Tags: angular, ng-template

I'm creating a tab component in Angular and i'm passing in the tabs like this:

```
<app-tabs>
  <app-tab label="first component">
    <app-my-first-component></app-my-first-component>
  </app-tab>
  <app-tab label="second component">
    <app-my-second-component></app-my-second-component>
  </app-tab>
</app-tabs>
```

The tabs components creates clickable headers and does a show/hide on the `app-tab`'s, so i can show the component corresponding to the label clicked.

My **problem** is this: Since my app has the two components in its template, the components gets created in the top `app` level. The show/hide works, but I want the components to trigger OnInit and OnDestroy (and get created/destroyed too) each time a tab is selected.

If i want to keep the layout shown above, how can i somehow pass the two user components as templates so they can get created/destroyed by the `app-tab` or `app-tabs` component? I would really like a solution where i wouldn't need to manually wrap the user components in `ng-template` in the example above - but have that somehow become the job of the `app-tab` component.

Comment: Can you show the `app-tab` html - or at least how the show/hide functionality works

Comment: @KurtHamilton i have tried different layouts for its html, but it doesn't matter how i do it - i won't work because the component is already created once i put it in the html for the app... My simplest is just this: `<ng-content *ngIf="show></ng-content>`

Comment: So is it still an open question? I was just interested in seeing the `app-tab` mechanism to help understand the problem.